# Failed SQL Azure Database Copy (Hanging?)

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

After performing the same operation many times before, unfortunately this time the same operation (which is an azure database copy) of [DatabaseX] from [AzureSQLServerA] to [AzureSQLServerB] seems to hang - and not sure how to terminate it?

The copy job never seemed to complete, and over a day has passed (in the past, this operation only takes a few hours for the same database and between the same servers).

Now I can not seem to perform any copies of any databases to that target server [AzureSQLServerB] even with another database (example, [DatabaseY]).  I receive the following notifications:

> (!) Error creating SQL database from copy.  SQL database from copy creation failed in resource group Test-Environment.
>
> (!) Failed to submit deployment.  Error submitting the deployment request.  Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: Unable to edit or replace deployment 'Microsoft.SQL.CopyDb': previous deployment from '10/13/2015 11:54:48{M' is still active (expiration time is '10/20/2015 11:54:48 PM').

Is my only option to wait the full timeout period (1 week?) before being able to try again? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you executing the database copy statement? TSQL, REST, PowerShell, Portal? If you are using TSQL, REST, or PowerShell, can you share some sample code of what you are doing?

Comment: Hi Brian, the copy command is executed just via the portal.  Thanks

Comment: Hey Stefan, I am an employee at Microsoft working on Azure SQL Database. If you don't mind, could you send me an email with your server name and the name of the database you are trying to copy? You can reach me at "elfish" at "Microsoft" dot com.

Comment: Thanks Elfisher, will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:  Performed the copy through the portal after the timeout period lapsed and it worked fine.  Must have been something locking it down, but not sure what.

Comment: Have had two occurrences of this sort of thing in the last four weeks, different servers, different elastic pools.  In our case we discovered (via the portal) that the source database was experiencing a resource health event.